# Reconsume Kafka Message that failed during processing due to DB error

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am new to Kafka and would like to seek advice on what is the best practice to handle such scenario.

**Scenario:**

I have a spring boot application that has a consumer method that is listening for messages via the `@KafkaListner` annotation. Once an incoming message has occurred, the consumer method will process the message, which simply performs database updates to different tables via `JdbcTemplate`.

If the updates to the tables are successful, I will manually commit the message by calling the `acknowledge()` method. If the database update fails, instead of calling the `acknowledge()` method, I will call the `nack()` method with a given duration (E.g. 10 seconds) such that the message will reappear again to be consumed.

**Things to note**

1. I am not concerned with the ordering of the messages. Whatever event comes I just have to consume and process it, that's all.
2. I am only given a topic (no retryable topic and no dead letter topic)

**Here is the problem**

If I do the above method, my consumer becomes inconsistent. Let's say if I call the `nack()` method with a duration of 1min, meaning to say after 1 min, the same message will reappear.

Within this 1 min, there could "x" number of incoming messages to be consumed and processed. The observation made was none of these messages are getting consumed and processed.

**What I want to know**

Hence, I hope someone will advise me what I am doing wrongly and what is the best practice / way to handle such scenarios.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Records are always received in order; there is no way to defer the current record until later, but continue to process other records after this one when consuming from a single topic.

Kafka topics are a linear log and not a queue.

You would need to send it to another topic; the `@RetryableTopic` (non-blocking retrties) feature is specifically designed for this use case.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#retry-topic

You could also increase the container concurrency so at least you could continue to process records from other partitions.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I have a new requirement now. What kafka consumer configuration can i set (E.g. request.timout.ms) such that if i do not call acknowledge() within lets say 3seconds, the broker will resend the same kafka message?

Comment: Don’t ask new questions in comments. There is no such configuration. You would have to throw an exception to get redelivery, with the default error handler.